# How do I fix this freezing website after the function runs second time?

Tags: javascript

So, when I run the function first time it works amazing and without any problems, but when I run it second time, the website just freezes and I can't do anything.

**Whole function:**

```
function changecurrentBadge() {
    var image = document.getElementById("currentdivbadge");
    var dropd = document.getElementById("old-division");
    image.src = dropd.options[dropd.selectedIndex].value;

    var name1 = document.getElementById("name1");

    var divisionsList = document.getElementById("old-division");
    var oldrankList = document.getElementById("old-rank");
    var changeRank = divisionsList.options[divisionsList.selectedIndex].value;

    if(dropd.value === "images/empty.png") {
        name1.innerHTML = "None";
    } else if (dropd.value === "images/security.png") {
        name1.innerHTML = "Security";
    } else if (dropd.value === "images/trainer.png") {
        name1.innerHTML = "Trainers";
    } else if (dropd.value === "images/detectives.png") {
        name1.innerHTML = "Detectives";
    } else if (dropd.value === "images/corporals.png") {
        name1.innerHTML = "Corporals";
    } else if (dropd.value === "images/sergeants.png") {
        name1.innerHTML = "Sergeants";
    } else if (dropd.value === "images/lieutenants.png") {
        name1.innerHTML = "Lieutenants";
    } else if (dropd.value === "images/captains.png") {
        name1.innerHTML = "Captains";
    } else if (dropd.value === "images/superintendents.png") {
        name1.innerHTML = "Superintendents";
    } else name1.innerHTML = "ERROR APPEARED";
    
    while (oldrankList.options.length) {
        divisionsList.remove(0);
        
    }
    var ranks = ranksList[changeRank];
    if (ranks) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
            var oldrank = new Option(ranks[i], i);
            oldrankList.options.add(oldrank);
        }
    }
}
```

**Whole Rank List:**

```
var ranksList = {};
ranksList['images/security.png'] = ['Trial Inspector', 'Armory Inspector', 'Inspector I', 'Inspector II', 'Inspector III', 'Inspector IV', 'Senior Armored Guard (S.A.G)', 'Asst. Head of Guards (A.H.G)', 'Head of Guards (H.o.G)'];
ranksList['images/trainer.png'] = ['Trial Master', 'Rookie Master', 'Junior Master', 'Master I', 'Master II', 'Master III', 'Master IV', 'Jr. Head Master', 'Head Master', 'Snr. Head Master'];
ranksList['images/detectives.png'] = ['Trial Detective', 'Probationary Detective', 'Junior Detective', 'Detective I', 'Detective II', 'Detective III', 'Senior Detective', 'Acting Supervisory Detective', 'Supervisory Detective', 'Detective in Charge'];
ranksList['images/corporals.png'] = ['Trial Corporal', 'Probationary Corporal', 'Junior Corporal', 'Corporal I', 'Corporal II', 'Corporal III', 'Senior Corporal', 'Lead Corporal', 'Head Corporal', 'Junior Corporal Chief', 'Senior Corporal Chief', 'Deputy Corporal in Charge', 'Corporal in Charge'];
ranksList['images/sergeants.png'] = ['Trial Sergeant', 'Probationary Sergeant', 'Junior Sergeant', 'Sergeant I', 'Sergeant II', 'Sergeant III', 'Senior Sergeant', 'Acting Supervisory Sergeant', 'Supervisory Sergeant', 'Sergeant in Charge'];
ranksList['images/lieutenants.png'] = ['Trial Lieutenant', 'Probationary Lieutenant', 'Junior Lieutenant', 'Lieutenant I', 'Lieutenant II', 'Lieutenant III', 'Senior Lieutenant', 'Acting Supervisory Lieutenant', 'Supervisory Lieutenant', 'Lieutenant in Charge'];
ranksList['images/captains.png'] = ['Trial Captain', 'Probationary Captain', 'Junior Captain', 'Captain I', 'Captain II', 'Captain III', 'Senior Captain', 'Acting Supervisory Captain', 'Supervisory Captain', 'Captain in Charge'];
ranksList['images/superintendents.png'] = ['Trial Superintendent', 'Probationary Superintendent', 'Junior Superintendent', 'Superintendent I', 'Superintendent II', 'Superintendent III', 'Senior Superintendent', 'Acting Supervisory Superintendent', 'Supervisory Superintendent', 'Superintendent in Charge'];
```

When I ran the console.log commands to see where it freezes, appearently the second log didn't run, which was in this code:

```
while (oldrankList.options.length) {
        divisionsList.remove(0);
        
    }
    var ranks = ranksList[changeRank];
    if (ranks) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
            var oldrank = new Option(ranks[i], i);
            oldrankList.options.add(oldrank);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The freezing is probably caused by an infinite loop. I guess its the while loop who never ends.

Answer (score 0):

You are running infinite loop in this code part.

```js
while (oldrankList.options.length) {
    divisionsList.remove(0);  
}
```

Try this.

```js
for(let j = 0; j < oldrankList.options.length; j++) {
    divisionsList.remove(0);              
}
```

Comment: It did fix the freeze problem, but now the drop down menu is broken and the second drop down menu loads ranks with both options selected in the first one, by also removing the first drop down menu options.